# Multiple inserts in one SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, bulkinsert

DB: SQL server

I am using the below construct for inserting multiple records into a table.  I am receiving the data (to be inserted) from other DB.

> Insert into table1 
>       select '1','2' UNION ALL
>       select '3','4' UNION ALL
>       select '5','6';

would there be any other chance in doing inserts in less turn around time. Its also been executed as a web request. I guess bulk insert would not fit here, as I don't have the data in a file to do a bulk insert.
Any suggestions please..

Answer (score 1):

If the source database is also a SQL Server, you could add a linked server and:

```
insert table1 select * from linkedserver.dbname.dbo.table1
```

If you're inserting from .NET code, the fastest way to insert multiple rows is [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx).  SqlBulkCopy does require DBO rights.

Comment: As the data is in other db, I could not directly involve that in select query. I fetch it to my variables and doing this insert

Comment: Yes I'm inserting from .Net, I will have a look Ando

Answer (score 0):

That is actually the best multiple insert I have ever seen. Just be careful to SQL injections, always use CommandParameters in ASP.NET or use mysql_real_escape in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this recently, coming from MySQL and expecting the syntax from cularis' answer, but after some searching all I could find is the syntax you posted in your answer.

**Edit**: Looks like cularis removed his answer, he was talking about the `INSERT INTO x VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4);` syntax.

Comment: @cularis it is possible in SQL Server 2008+

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2008 and stored procedures, you could always make use of table valued parameters:

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters

It then becomes an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT * FROM ...`

This would help against injection problems.  Not sure if this is possible with parameterised SQL.